# How to hide action archive, unarchive and export for crm_lead in odoo version 16

Tags: javascript, python, css, xml, odoo

[I tried many ways like customize js file, ... But it's failse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJG2L.png)

How to hide action archive, unarchive and export for crm_lead in odoo version 16. I tried many ways but is failse. Please help me for issue and thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom module and create am inherited view inside

```xml
<odoo>
    <data>
        <!-- Inherit the original view of crm.lead -->
        <record id="view_crm_lead_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">crm.lead.custom</field>
            <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_lead_view_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <xpath expr="//header/button[@name='archive']" position="attributes">
                        <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                    </xpath>
                    <xpath expr="//header/button[@name='unarchive']" position="attributes">
                        <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                    </xpath>
                    <xpath expr="//header/button[@name='export']" position="attributes">
                        <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                    </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

ALTERNATIVELY: In Odoo > Settings > Technical > Views, you can search for the view that you want to modify, it should be something like : "crm_lead_view_form", open it, click on the Edit button and create an inherited view to remove the unwanted contextual actions (archive, unarchive, export):

```xml
<xpath expr="//header" position="inside">
    <button name="archive" position="replace"></button>
    <button name="unarchive" position="replace"></button>
    <button name="export" position="replace"></button>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Thank you but it seems that editing like that is not suitable for the version i am using which is odoo16

Answer (score 0):

The "Archive" action can be removed by removing the `active` field from the view. Setting it invisible is not enough.

For the "Export" action it looks much more difficult. In Odoo Vanilla (without customization) you can just remove export access from users. But that will lead to having no export access anywhere.
If you want to have more precise possibilities to configure export access, you have to find a ready module or have to make one yourself.

I see two possible approaches, but there are more:

1. Extend/Change the JavaScript Part of Odoo where it is adding the action. A hint: search for `isExportEnable` in the JS code.
2. Override `export_data()` on `crm.lead` and just implement your "export access logic" in that method. That solution is not the best, because the "Export" action is still there, but it will work with regard to data restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Inherited the 'active' field and add groups and specify which groups you want to have access to it.

For example:

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class HrAppraisalInherited(models.Model):
   _inherit = "hr.appraisal"

   active = fields.Boolean(groups="hr.group_hr_manager")
```